# Data does not display in table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, api

I am new in JQuery  and API, here i am trying to retrieve data from SQL in JSON format and then bind it to table. Data is returned here `return details.ToString();` when I debug but it does not bind data into table. Any Error here?

Controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    static EmpRepository repository = new EmpRepository();

    public string GetData(Employee Em) {
        var re = repository.GetData(Em);
        return re;
    }

}
```

Repository Class:

```
public  string GetData(Employee Em)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    List<Employee> details = new List<Employee>();

    connection();
    com = new SqlCommand("select FirstName, LastName, Company from Employee", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    da.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        Employee user = new Employee();
        //user.Id = Int32.Parse(string dr["Id"]);
        user.FirstName = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
        user.LastName = dr["LastName"].ToString();
        user.Company = dr["Company"].ToString();
        details.Add(user);
    }
    return details.ToString();
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function DisplayResult() {
    var Emp = {};
    var url = 'api/Employee/GetData';
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        //data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++)
            {
                $("#tbDetails").appendTo("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].FirstName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].LastName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Company + "</td></tr>");
            }
        },

        error: function (result) {

            alert("error");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You are returning it as `string` from `api` and expecting `json` as response in your `ajax` with `dataType: "json"` property set.. Try returning `Json` data from `api`..

Comment: How to return it as `josn` from api?

Comment: ever tried `return details;`

Comment: Change `public  string GetData` to `public JsonResult GetData` and `return Json(details)` at the end..

Comment: This code `return Json(details)` shows an error, the name `json` doesnt exist in current context !

Comment: Did you change your JQuery as my answer?

Comment: before changing Jquery, c# code must be correct if not JQuery code will not work at all

Comment: yes already changed but this shows an error `return Json(re);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two mistakes in your code.

- On "public  string GetData(Employee Em) "
  I think that you want to return list of  Employee
  so should change `return details.ToString(); to`***return details;***`

It will be

```
public  List<Employee> GetData(Employee Em)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    List<Employee> details = new List<Employee>();

   connection();
    com = new SqlCommand("select FirstName, LastName, Company from Employee", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Employee user = new Employee();
               // user.Id = Int32.Parse(string dr["Id"]);
                user.FirstName = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                user.LastName = dr["LastName"].ToString();
                user.Company = dr["Company"].ToString();
                details.Add(user);


            }
            return details; }
```

-Change GetData api, must return **JSON format**. It will be as below

```
 public string GetData(Employee Em) {
    var re = repository.GetData(Em);
    return Json(re);}
```

and

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++)
    {
        $("#tbDetails").appendTo("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].FirstName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].LastName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Company + "</td></tr>");
    }
```

change to

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        $("#tbDetails").appendTo("<tr><td>" + data[i].FirstName + "</td><td>" + data[i].LastName + "</td><td>" + data[i].Company + "</td></tr>");
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: `return Json(re);` can not convert  list to string!

Comment: look at my update, return data object in JQuery must be a object via JSON format not string.

Comment: this return code `return Json(re);` still shows an error, it cannot convert list into string!

Comment: Did you change your JQuery as my answer? No need convert to string

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes you need to do each section.

First in your Repository just return the details as is not details.ToString()

Next in both your repository class as well as in WebApi controller you don't need to Employee parameter you are not using it anywhere. Remove it.

Repository Class ->

```
public  string GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<Employee> details = new List<Employee>();

       connection();
        com = new SqlCommand("select FirstName, LastName, Company from Employee", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Employee user = new Employee();
                   // user.Id = Int32.Parse(string dr["Id"]);
                    user.FirstName = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                    user.LastName = dr["LastName"].ToString();
                    user.Company = dr["Company"].ToString();
                    details.Add(user);


                }
                return details;

            }
```

WebApi Controller :

You don't need to convert anything to JSON here, by default JSON.NET serializer will convert your List to JSON Array of Employee Objects.

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        static EmpRepository repository = new EmpRepository();

        public string GetData() {
            var re = repository.GetData();
            return re;
        }

    }
```

Now in your jquery :

Ideally you are doing a 'GET' here not a POST , data returned now is an array of employee objects iterate through it.

```
 $(document).ready(function DisplayResult() {
    var Emp = {};
    var url = 'api/Employee/GetData';
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                $("#tbDetails").appendTo("<tr><td>" + data[i].FirstName + "</td><td>" + data[i].LastName + "</td><td>" + data[i].Company + "</td></tr>");
            }
        },

        error: function (result) {

            alert("error");
        }
    });

});
```